# What really happened - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, movies

The last thing you remembered,
Or what happened at the start.
From reality dismembered?
That is a magician's art.

He really wasn't funny,
Neither the following curse.
Can't sleep, dark or sunny,
Across the universe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> Christopher Nolan, as described by his filmography.  Each line is a different movie.

The last thing you remembered,

> **Memento**

Or what happened at the start.

> **Batman Begins** (Could also be **Inception** if you take the title literally).

From reality dismembered?

> **Inception**

That is a magician's art.

> **The Prestige**

He really wasn't funny,

> **The Dark Knight** (featuring The Joker)

Neither the following curse.

> **Following**

Can't sleep, dark or sunny,

> **Insomnia**

Across the universe.

> **Interstellar**

Comment: Well done. For "the following curse", I was thinking more Bane from DK Rises, but that works as well.

Comment: Nice riddle, and that's a fun coincidence that the same clue worked for two movies. Am I right that the puzzle title references the tendency in these movies to have a twist at the end that recontextualizes the beginning ("What really happened")?

Comment: Yep. Inception was the main one on my mind, but most of his seem to follow that direction.